# SQL Server Filtered Index for Unique Constraint

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have a database table that looks like this (with unimportant columns ommitted):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ImageDocument_FaxProperties](
    [FaxPropertyID] [int] PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Agent] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [ParentImageDocumentId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
)
```

I want to create a constraint where the same Agent can have multiple rows as long as the ParentImageDocumentIds are the same on each row, but an Agent cannot have rows with different ParentImageDocumentIds. I understand this isn't a good table structure, but it's legacy & I'm not allowed to change it. NULL ParentImageDocumentIds should be considered different.

For example:

```
PK   Agent      ParentImageDocumentId  -This is ok
#    person1    {D09C3900-0300}        {.. other columns ..}
#    person1    {D09C3900-0300}        {.. other columns ..}

PK   Agent      ParentImageDocumentId  -Check constraint prevents 2nd row insertion
#    person1    NULL                   {.. other columns ..}
#    person1    NULL                   {.. other columns ..}

PK   Agent      ParentImageDocumentId  -Check constraint prevents 2nd row insertion
#    person1    NULL                   {.. other columns ..}
#    person1    {A13E5B21-93DE}        {.. other columns ..}

PK   Agent      ParentImageDocumentId  -Check constraint prevents 2nd row insertion
#    person1    {D09C3900-0300}        {.. other columns ..}
#    person1    {A13E5B21-93DE}        {.. other columns ..}
```

I'm wondering what's the best way to write a constraint for this. A unique index on Agent won't work, because they can sometimes have both. A unique on Agent, ParentImageDocumentId  would allow them to have different GUIDs, which is not okay. A filtered index with "WHERE ParentImageDocumentId IS NULL AND Agent IS NOT NULL" will work to prevent double NULLs, but not different GUIDs or GUID & NULL.

Below are two working solutions, however I'm wondering if there's a better way. An indexed schemabound view allows me to create a more complicated filtered index. An alternative was a table-level check constraint using a function, this should work, but adding the check constraint is SUPER SLOW. I'm guessing it's re-running my function for every row in the table, but that should be unnecessary for adding a table-level constraint since the function is not checking a specific row. Is there a way around this? I'm leaning towards the indexed view, but wondered if there are alternatives (aside from change my table structure) & which alternative is the best.

Solution #1:

```
CREATE VIEW ImageDocument_FaxProperties_Assignments WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT Agent, ParentImageDocumentId, COUNT_BIG(*) as numPages FROM dbo.ImageDocument_FaxProperties
    WHERE Status IN ( 'PROC', 'LINKING' )
    AND Agent IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Agent, ParentImageDocumentId
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_ImageDocument_FaxProperties_Assignments_Unique] ON [ImageDocument_FaxProperties_Assignments] (Agent)
GO
```

Solution #2:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ImageDocument_FaxProperties_Assignments_CheckConstraint() RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result BIT = 0;
    WITH Assignments AS
    (SELECT Agent, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Agent ORDER BY ParentImageDocumentId) AS assignmentNum
    FROM dbo.ImageDocument_FaxProperties
    WHERE Status IN ( 'PROC', 'LINKING' )
    AND Agent IS NOT NULL
    )

    SELECT @Result = 1 FROM Assignments WHERE assignmentNum > 1

    RETURN @Result
END
GO
ALTER TABLE [ImageDocument_FaxProperties]
ADD CONSTRAINT ImageDocument_FaxProperties_Assignments_Unique CHECK (dbo.ImageDocument_FaxProperties_Assignments_CheckConstraint() = 0)
```

Comment: FWIW, udf-based solution resulted in frequent deadlocks for me. Filtered view worked better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexed view will be the better option of the two you propose.

This kind of logic in UDFs is inefficient (it **is** evaluated for each row) and difficult to get right. See for example the following posts

- [Scalar UDFs wrapped in CHECK constraints are very slow and may fail for multirow updates](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx)
- [Snapshot isolation: A threat for integrity? (Part 4)](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/09/15/Snapshot-and-integrity-part-4.aspx)

Comment: Wow. Great information in those links. Thank you! I'll definitely be careful when using check constraints in the future.

Comment: Is it possible to use a row_number() function instead